# How to disable sync event on model's save method in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Model's save method by default triggers sync event after the server has acknowledged the change. Is there any way to silence that sync event on model's save?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [the portion of the `save` method that calls `sync`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-66) in the annotated source:

```
model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
```

It’s pretty deep in there. You *could* override the `save` method to remove that line.

Why do you want to do this?